# Discord.js : Add a role on a specific server to a user that DM the bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I am currently developing a discord bot, and I would like to add the role "Members" on my server to any users that DM the bot. However I can't manage to make addRole work. I keep getting the following error :

> TypeError: member.guild.roles.cache.addRole is not a function

This is my code :

```
let server = client.guilds.cache.get('myserverID')
var memberRole= server.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Member")
let member = server.members.cache.get(msg.author.id);
member.guild.roles.cache.addRole(memberRole)
```

Could someone please help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because that method doesn't exist: the method you need to use is [`GuildMember.roles.add()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add).
Here's how you can apply it to your code:

```js
let server = client.guilds.cache.get('myserverID')
var memberRole= server.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Member")
let member = server.members.cache.get(msg.author.id)

member.roles.add(memberRole)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try`member.guild.roles.cache.roles.add(memberRole);`instead of `member.roles.add(memberRole);`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work unfortunately, I get this : TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined.

Comment: No, it's not that: you're calling the `add` method from the cache Collection instead of the role manager. [Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager)

Answer (score -1):

It's

```
 member.guild.roles.cache.add(memberRole)
```

not

```
member.guild.roles.cache.addRole(memberRole)
```

Comment: No, it's not that: you're calling the `add` method from the cache Collection instead of the role manager. [Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager)

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately as I get this error : TypeError: member.guild.roles.cache.add is not a function

Comment: I didn't test it, I even asked in the discord.js server and they told me it was ok. Oh well